# Cookies instead of sessions?

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

What I've read and know about sessions is that they aren't really reliable with all that session id hijacking and stuff. So I decided I won't use sessions in my project, I'd rather just go with ordinary cookies and hope for the best.

So basically what I have set up is kind of like a session but hopefully will be harder to crack. Unfortunately I seem to be unable to build it hard-to-crack. So basically I guess this is more of a security question rather than the choice between cookies or sessions, but I cannot seem to find this in any straight text.

What am I supposed to hash in the session cookie and how? I've read that hashing algorithms can collide and it's just a matter of seconds before an attacker can create a string that would collide, with what is actually in the cookie, when hashed even though it may not be the same. I guess what I'm trying to ask is what is the proper way of saving this information in a cookie and actually what information should I store there?

I know that basically with `httpOnly` no attacker should be able to grab a hold of a cookie but I suppose that this project may and probably wont use `SSL` so there's the old tapping method available. I know that I'm trying to build a skyscraper with sticks and stones here but asking is still worth a shot.

Comment: this is just wrong from the opening sentence.

Comment: You're afraid of approach A, because you read somewhere that it's unreliable (without understanding the reasons). So you turn to approach B, which in unreliable by its very nature, and now ask SO about how to fix it. Wrong indeed.

Comment: this is why people wear tin foil hats, they read about the CIA mind probes.

Comment: You seem very confused, but it is hard to figure out the source of your confusion just from the question. Can you explain what specific problem you are trying to solve? (E.g. what type of attack made you avoid session handling? Session hijacking is not supposed to happen if you set up your system properly.)

Comment: @Tgr Yes, I am indeed very confused. If I switch to sessions, then how would I re-start a session from a `remember me` cookie. What information should I put in the cookie that no attacker could ever recreate that cookie and start a valid session of another user's account? This I cannot seem to find an answer to.

Comment: The concept of sessions is fairly straightforward: instead of storing stuff in cookies, you store them locally, assign them an identifier and only store that in a cookie. The end result is similar, but the user, or attackers snooping on the connection cannot read or manipulate the data, and you have less traffic. There are lots of things you can get wrong with sessions, like making the session identifier easy to guess, but all those you would get wrong (ow worse) with cookies as well. I honestly can't think of any attack that would be harder to pull off against cookies than against a session.

Comment: @Tgr I get it, I have now switched to sessions, but I don't understand how to particularly identify a `remember me` cookie. If an attacker was to grab a hold of some user's `remember me cookie` and recreate it in his own browser he would start a new valid session as the user he'd stolen it from. Even if I were to put some device-specific (kind of) information like OS + browser + versions and hash it, the attacker would still be able to create a hash collision and still activate the session. Please help me out on this one `:<`

Comment: If you want to defend against an attacker which can snoop on the requests between the server and the user, you need SSL, there is no way around it. User agents can be faked, and man-in-the-middle attacks usually happen on public wifi networks so the attacker has the same IP address as well. SSL is expensive, though, and often no real harm can be done by stealing the session, so most small-to-mediam sites simply ignore this threat.

Comment: If the attacker does not have physical access to the network, though, then the only way he can steal a cookie (short of compromising the users computer) is to run malicious javascript on your site (that is called an XSS attack). `httpOnly` cookies help to mitigate that somewhat, but not much, so you have to be careful to avoid XSS. Sanitize input, escape output etc. - it's a big topic.

Comment: @Tgr Thank you very much for your replies. I have read about XSS thus all my session and ordinary cookies are `httpOnly`. I suppose SSL is not going to be an option for this project any time soon due to really low budget. So what I've come to think of as a possible solution is, even though this may be a little irritating to users, ask just for a password when a session has expired. I guess that would make the `remember me` functionality not a real `remember me` but hey, it's better than someone stealing your account. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

The problem with eschewing sessions entirely is that some values should not be user settable. For example, if you had a session variable `is_logged_in`, which is set only when the user successfully authenticates, then it'll be tricky to implement this with a cookie securely. The problem there is that the user can set their own cookie (since it comes from the client side) and log themselves in without a password.

Now, you could use this approach by storing the user's credentials in cookies and authenticating for every request, but that too suffers from a number of problems. Firstly, it is a good idea to limit how often you send credentials to the server in plaintext; if you use sessions, then you send them only once. Secondly, this approach means that passwords are stored on the local computer unencrypted (stored passwords for websites are usually encrypted with a master password**). So, this approach arguably worsens the user's overall security.

You *could* mitigate these problems by logging on, and have your login system set encrypted cookies (using symmetric encryption). These would be decrypted and authenticated for every request, and would be safe to transmit for every request, and would be safer to store on local computer cookies. However, here you are adding quite a bit of complexity.

Thus, I'd be inclined to advise that you persist with using sessions, but do the necessary reading around any security issues that arise.

---

** *Recently it was found that Chrome stores saved passwords in plaintext, with no option to encrypt them with a master password ([see here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=chrome+stores+passwords+in+plain+text)). This started a debate online about whether some security features are just "theatre" (i.e. only look secure without actually adding tangible extra security).*

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you want to replace cookies (from sessions) with cookies. Doesn't make sense!